# HTML inside Twitter Bootstrap 3 popover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to make html inside popover. But it doesn't works .

```
<a class="tasks-menu" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Tasks</a>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none">HIDDEN CONTENT</div>

$(function(){

    $('[data-toggle=popover].tasks-menu').popover({ 
        html : true, 
        content: function() {
          return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you expect the HIDDEN CONTENT to be hidden?

Comment: It have to be hidden by default. 'display:block' on clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap popover works fine with your code. If you want to put the entire html of `popover_content_wrapper` inside the popover, you should use .clone() instead of .html()

http://www.bootply.com/121357

.html() will just get the inside of `popover_content_wrapper`, which results in the text  "HIDDEN CONTENT" to show in the popover

Comment: I Found solution =))                                                 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/docs.min.js"></script>                                     docs.min <<<< this file blocked popover